# can't scan whatsApp web qr code?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

i have htc wildfire 3 
i can not scan qr code for whatsApp web 
i see the "OK, got it" button , no problem with that 
but it seems camera keep scanning but not getting anything
any idea how to fix that ?
every thing is updated already

Comment: Related questions with suggestions [http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=whatsapp+QR+is%3Aquestion](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=whatsapp+QR+is%3Aquestion)

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me once because I had a slow internet connection. Connect to a high speed internet and try again.